# Wired network connection crashes router

Tags: ethernet

I have an RPi2B and an RPi3B. Both of them crash my router (ASUS AC68U) some time after wiring them to the network physically. After the router crash happened, all of my other devices (tablets, smartphones, PC's, some wired, some wifi) lose connection to the network. I can't even reach the configuration page of the router from my PC and ping to the router fails. The only way to get the network back is to unpower the router and switching it back on.

Some strange facts around this:

- with a WiFi connection (for the RPi2B I have to use a WiFi dongle of course) the crash doesn't happen and everything works fine (forever)
- with a wired connection it works fine for like 10 minutes (so no DHCP problem I guess) until the crash happens
- it happens with Raspbian as well as LibreElec, so it isn't probably an OS problem

Because WiFi works, it doesn't hurt too much. But it leaves me with the feeling that I must have done something wrong.

Anyone got a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: This would seem to be a problem with your router (or possibly cabling).

Comment: I am not familiar with the ASUS AC68U: is there something like logfiles you can check or a system status history? I doubt you'll find any useful hints if you check the RPi's logfiles, but have you tried?

Comment: @Fabian: Strangely, the log file (as shown in the web page) of the router shows nothing interesting as far as I can see - just the reboot traces. I think I have once tried "logcat" on the pi, but it didn't know it. It's been some time since I have used linux though, and probably I don't know what to look for.

Comment: You can read the main logfile on the RPi by `less /var/log/syslog` (scroll with page up/down or arrow keys) or search for keywords by `grep -i error /var/log/syslog` (this will show lines containing the word "error", case insensitive). I would grep for "fail", too, but don't waste much time with the RPi logfiles, they probably will not help. Like Milliways commeted: cabling, this seems more worth to investigate. Can you replace all network cables? Are your RPis doing anything that can cause heavy load on the router? Can you monitor the routers temperature or check it when it crashes again?

Comment: I'll check the log files of the Pi. If the router was an ordinary machine, I'd just plug in a keyboard & screen and check what's going on in the live system, but since the network is the only access path, the network crash is the worst case scenario. Anyways, I'll switch cables also. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

So I had this problem with an RP 4, within 5 mins the router would crash.  As silly as it sounds, changing the network cable ro a different brand means its been running for around 5 hours with no crashes.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will keep that in mind. I have an RPI4 on my desk, but I haven't found the time to do some more thorough testing. But, surprisingly, last time I tried it, everything went fine for like at least 30min-1h before I turned it off. Should the Router crash again, I will try your cable suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled on this question after experiencing the same issue with my RPi 4 crashing my Asus router.

It turns out that my Pi's case fan was intermittently failing. When the fan stopped and the Pi got very warm, it also crashed the router. Replacing the case/fan and keeping an eye on the CPU temperature has helped: I haven't experienced any issues now that the Pi isn't overheating.  Hope this thread helps someone else too.